# 404 error: Trying to deploy ocelot gateway inside docker to call microservices

Tags: asp.net, docker, webapi, ocelot

We have developed two ASP.NET CORE (5.0) microservices and deployed them inside docker
http://localhost:28621/stock
http://localhost:62362/user

Both are easily accessible from browser.

### We have used ocelot gateway for API gateway.
When we deployed it inside docker we got following error

`warn: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0] requestId: 0HM8658EF6KHC:00000002, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /user, verb: GET. warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0] requestId: 0HM8658EF6KHC:00000002, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /user, verb: GET. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/user, request method: GET`  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ocelot.Development.json is as follows

```
 {
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/user",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 62362
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/user",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/stock",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 28621
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/stock",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5021"
  }
}
```

---

### startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOcelot();

    }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        await app.UseOcelot();
    }
}
```

---

### program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
              Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                   {
                       config.AddJsonFile($"ocelot.                                          
 {hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);
                   })
                  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                  {
                      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                  });
    }
```

---

Please guide us where we are doing mistake
we are using .net core 5.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change **Routes to ReRoutes**. I fixed myself with that. Maybe you forgot to add json file in the program.cs. Here is the code,

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) => 
{
config.AddJsonFile("Ocelot.json", false, true); 
})
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
{ 
webBuilder .UseStartup<Startup>(); 
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29915074)

Comment: Please [edit] to add that additional info to the answer itself.

Comment: I tried i hope it works for you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Ocelot container cannot access the other containers' services with "DownstreamHostAndPorts" settings: {'Host': 'localhost'}. Container's 'localhost' is not the same as the host machine's 'localhost'!

To solve this issue look in this direction:

- Create a Docker network
- Run all three containers under the same network with --network-alias flag
- In the Ocelot json file use the network alias names and default ports (since the containers can talk to eachother directly, there is no need to map external ports!)